# Comparing variable with File names bash

Tags: bash, file, compare

I've recently started to learn bash script and have started to create a file repository system. I have gotten pretty far and am able to add files, remove files. When I remove a file from the repository it actually leaves the file in but changes permissions so only the user that removed can use it, it then send a copy to there home area, it also changes the name of the file left behind to "$fileNameOUT"

I know plan to add a feature to my add function which checks after a file has been added if there is a file with the same name but with "OUT" at the end, if it finds this the old file will be sent to a back folder so files can be restored. I know I have to loop through the directory using a for loop, however the problem I'm having is I don't know how I can compare the file I have just added to all of the files in the directory.

I hope someone can make send of what I just wrote.

Comment: `I hope someone can make send of what I just wrote.` -- To be honest, it's pretty tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name of the file you are interested in, you can use the `-e` test to check if it exists.

```
if [ -e fooOUT ]
then
echo File exists
fi
```